# Code generation time

Tags: performance, algorithm, compiler-construction

For a relatively simple (algorithmically) languagec such as C, how much time is spent in the code generation phase compared to parsing/lexing/semantic analysis? I'm interested in a more general answer or even that it's quite implementation-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GCC to emit statistics using `-fstats`. Here's an example summary, produced by gcc4.5:

```
Execution times (seconds)
 callgraph construction:   0.05 ( 1%) usr   0.06 ( 2%) sys   0.14 ( 1%) wall    2885 kB ( 1%) ggc
 callgraph optimization:   0.14 ( 2%) usr   0.05 ( 2%) sys   0.26 ( 2%) wall    4433 kB ( 1%) ggc
 ipa cp                :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall     430 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa reference         :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall      11 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa pure const        :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.04 ( 0%) wall      31 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa SRA               :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 1%) wall    5280 kB ( 2%) ggc
 cfg cleanup           :   0.08 ( 1%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.12 ( 1%) wall     102 kB ( 0%) ggc
 trivially dead code   :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df multiple defs      :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df reaching defs      :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df live regs          :   0.06 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.17 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df live&initialized regs:   0.05 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df use-def / def-use chains:   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df reg dead/unused notes:   0.08 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 1%) wall    1165 kB ( 0%) ggc
 register information  :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 alias analysis        :   0.07 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall    2993 kB ( 1%) ggc
 alias stmt walking    :   0.05 ( 1%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.10 ( 1%) wall       5 kB ( 0%) ggc
 register scan         :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall      10 kB ( 0%) ggc
 rebuild jump labels   :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 preprocessing         :   0.16 ( 2%) usr   0.15 ( 6%) sys   0.34 ( 3%) wall    1508 kB ( 0%) ggc
 parser                :   0.99 (12%) usr   0.36 (14%) sys   1.24 (10%) wall  102915 kB (33%) ggc
 name lookup           :   0.50 ( 6%) usr   0.68 (26%) sys   1.25 (10%) wall   19025 kB ( 6%) ggc
 inline heuristics     :   0.10 ( 1%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.13 ( 1%) wall    2310 kB ( 1%) ggc
 integration           :   0.24 ( 3%) usr   0.08 ( 3%) sys   0.29 ( 2%) wall   32982 kB (10%) ggc
 tree gimplify         :   0.12 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall   10967 kB ( 3%) ggc
 tree eh               :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall    2932 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree CFG construction :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.04 ( 0%) wall    6725 kB ( 2%) ggc
 tree CFG cleanup      :   0.15 ( 2%) usr   0.03 ( 1%) sys   0.15 ( 1%) wall     531 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree VRP              :   0.11 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.12 ( 1%) wall    9477 kB ( 3%) ggc
 tree copy propagation :   0.09 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.09 ( 1%) wall    2850 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree find ref. vars   :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 0%) wall     422 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree PTA              :   0.27 ( 3%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.33 ( 3%) wall    2279 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree PHI insertion    :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall     325 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA rewrite      :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall    5069 kB ( 2%) ggc
 tree SSA other        :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.03 ( 1%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall     547 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA incremental  :   0.15 ( 2%) usr   0.03 ( 1%) sys   0.17 ( 1%) wall     819 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree operand scan     :   0.12 ( 1%) usr   0.08 ( 3%) sys   0.25 ( 2%) wall   16876 kB ( 5%) ggc
 dominator optimization:   0.07 ( 1%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.04 ( 0%) wall    2663 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree SRA              :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall      94 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree CCP              :   0.07 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall    2507 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree PHI const/copy prop:   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall       7 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree split crit edges :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall     991 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree reassociation    :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall     888 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree PRE              :   0.15 ( 2%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.15 ( 1%) wall    3586 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree FRE              :   0.07 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.14 ( 1%) wall    2627 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree code sinking     :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 0%) wall     470 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree linearize phis   :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall      17 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree forward propagate:   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 0%) wall     878 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree phiprop          :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall      24 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree conservative DCE :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.04 ( 2%) sys   0.04 ( 0%) wall      27 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree aggressive DCE   :   0.12 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.15 ( 1%) wall    7686 kB ( 2%) ggc
 tree DSE              :   0.08 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 0%) wall     285 kB ( 0%) ggc
 PHI merge             :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall      44 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree loop bounds      :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall      33 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree loop invariant motion:   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 complete unrolling    :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall    1000 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree vectorization    :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall     686 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree slp vectorization:   0.06 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.07 ( 1%) wall    4623 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree iv optimization  :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall     671 kB ( 0%) ggc
 predictive commoning  :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall      58 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree loop init        :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall     824 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree NRV optimization :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall      18 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree rename SSA copies:   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dominance frontiers   :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dominance computation :   0.27 ( 3%) usr   0.04 ( 2%) sys   0.23 ( 2%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 control dependences   :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 expand                :   0.93 (11%) usr   0.34 (13%) sys   1.18 (10%) wall   22542 kB ( 7%) ggc
 varconst              :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 0%) wall     456 kB ( 0%) ggc
 jump                  :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall     351 kB ( 0%) ggc
 forward prop          :   0.08 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.10 ( 1%) wall    1368 kB ( 0%) ggc
 CSE                   :   0.13 ( 2%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.12 ( 1%) wall     162 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dead code elimination :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dead store elim1      :   0.11 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall     612 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dead store elim2      :   0.13 ( 2%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.09 ( 1%) wall     932 kB ( 0%) ggc
 loop analysis         :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall     503 kB ( 0%) ggc
 loop invariant motion :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall      67 kB ( 0%) ggc
 CPROP                 :   0.13 ( 2%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.10 ( 1%) wall    1024 kB ( 0%) ggc
 PRE                   :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall     118 kB ( 0%) ggc
 CSE 2                 :   0.09 ( 1%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall     221 kB ( 0%) ggc
 branch prediction     :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall    1578 kB ( 1%) ggc
 combiner              :   0.10 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 1%) wall     679 kB ( 0%) ggc
 if-conversion         :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall     953 kB ( 0%) ggc
 regmove               :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall       1 kB ( 0%) ggc
 integrated RA         :   0.35 ( 4%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.34 ( 3%) wall    4128 kB ( 1%) ggc
 reload                :   0.20 ( 2%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.31 ( 3%) wall    2554 kB ( 1%) ggc
 reload CSE regs       :   0.11 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.13 ( 1%) wall    1551 kB ( 0%) ggc
 load CSE after reload :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       1 kB ( 0%) ggc
 thread pro- & epilogue:   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 1%) wall    3980 kB ( 1%) ggc
 if-conversion 2       :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall     456 kB ( 0%) ggc
 combine stack adjustments:   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 peephole 2            :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall     124 kB ( 0%) ggc
 hard reg cprop        :   0.06 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall      31 kB ( 0%) ggc
 scheduling 2          :   0.42 ( 5%) usr   0.02 ( 1%) sys   0.36 ( 3%) wall     630 kB ( 0%) ggc
 machine dep reorg     :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.04 ( 0%) wall       6 kB ( 0%) ggc
 reorder blocks        :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall     919 kB ( 0%) ggc
 final                 :   0.05 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.10 ( 1%) wall    1187 kB ( 0%) ggc
 symout                :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.04 ( 0%) wall     148 kB ( 0%) ggc
 plugin execution      :   0.18 ( 2%) usr   0.32 (12%) sys   0.43 ( 4%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 TOTAL                 :   8.48             2.64            12.15             315665 kB
```

Comment: `cc1: warning: command line option "-fstats" is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C`  Oops!  Luckily, the program I'm trying can be compiled as either C or C++.  I suspect that the above results may have been produced with a translation unit that was rather light on header file material. P.S `ObjC++`, wha?

Comment: @Kaz this was 1/2 year ago. IIRC, it was my base library -- or the bottom of the dependency chain. good hypothesis =) ObjC++ is a dialect which supports ObjC and C++ in the same TU. there are restrictions, e.g. objects should not derive from the other lang, and you can't declare objc symbols in namespaces. it also takes quite a bit of time to compile.

Answer (score 2):

C compilers spend most of their time reading header files in my experience. I used to use a C compiler that printed statistics on that and even quite simple 100 line files would include 10,000 lines of headers if they were doing enough system calls.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this really depends on the compiler and the algorithms chosen for each phase. In general, lexing/parsing will be very cheap, analysis and optimization will be expensive, and code generation will be somewhere in between.

Code generation normally includes instruction selection, scheduling, and register allocation. There may be other phases depending on your compiler.

- Instruction selection is the process of translating your intermediate representation into architecture-specific instructions. The simplest way to do this is just to have a fixed sequence for every IR instruction; this would give poor code, but is very fast, so you might see this in a JIT compiler. In ahead-of-time compiled languages like C, you will have a "tiling" algorithm which covers your IR with tiles representing machine instructions. Different algorithms exist, such as maximal much, a greedy algorithm using by LLVM. All algorithms I know of are O(n) but some take multiple passes. In general, the more optimal the tiling, the longer it takes.
- Instruction scheduling is arranging the instructions so they will execute with as few stalls as possible on a specific CPU. This phase is highly CPU specific (not just architecture specific). This phase is optional.
- Register allocation is assigning variables to registers or stack slots. Again, there are several algorithms. Graph coloring is good, but it has to be approximated since true graph coloring is NP-complete. Linear scan (used by LLVM) is much faster, but not as good. Both algorithms are O(n).

Answer (score 0):

By code generation, I am assuming you are referring to the generation of object code?  If so, that's a relatively quick process.  Most compilers make use of one or more intermediate representations (IR) to ease analysis/optimization.  By the time this IR needs to be generated into object code, it is relatively low level and thus very similar to the target object code.  This makes it extremely simple to output object code.  It should be possible to generate this final object code in a single pass.

Comment: Code optimization itself can take quite some time and in many cases is controllable by the programmer as there are special compiler/linker optimization options that can be specified (e.g. -O2 in gcc).